# Boundaries of Northern Ireland Local Government Districts (LGD2014)?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries

I'm looking for boundaries for Northern Ireland's **Local Government Districts** (**LGD2014**). 
I only find a [list of units](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/local-government-districts-december-2016-names-and-codes-in-northern-ireland2), but no the boundaries. There are [11 LGDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_government_in_Northern_Ireland#Local_Government_Districts).

Does anybody know where to find the boundaries at a decent scale for analysis?

Comment: NI opendata https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/boundary-commission-for-northern-ireland-revised-proposals

Comment: Thanks, but these seem to be different boundaries. There are 11 districts in the dataset. I added the info to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Government Districts (LGD2014) boundaries found it at 
https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/osni-open-data-largescale-boundaries-local-government-districts-20121